# An inequality about sequences in a $\sigma$-algebra

Tags: measure-theory, inequality, supremum-and-infimum

Let $(X,\mathbb X,\mu)$ be a measure space and let $(E_n)$ be a sequence in $\mathbb X$. Show that $$\mu(\lim\inf E_n)\leq\lim\inf\mu(E_n).$$

I am quite sure I need to use the following lemma.

**Lemma**. Let $\mu$ be a measure defined on a $\sigma$-algebra $\mathbb X$.

1. If $(E_n)$ is an increasing sequence in $\mathbb X$, then 
   $$\mu\left(\bigcup_{n=1}^\infty E_n\right)=\lim\mu(E_n).$$
2. If $(F_n)$ is a decreasing sequence in $\mathbb X$ and if $\mu(F_1)<+\infty$, then 
   $$\mu\left(\bigcap_{n=1}^\infty F_n\right)=\lim\mu(F_n).$$

I know that
$$\mu(\liminf_n E_n)=\mu\left(\bigcup_{i=1}^\infty\bigcap_{n=i}^\infty E_n\right)=
\lim_i\mu\left(\bigcap_{n=i}^\infty E_n\right).$$
The first equality follows from the definition of $\lim\inf$ and the second from point 1 of the lemma above. Here is where I am stuck.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Note that $\mu\left(\bigcap_{n=i}^\infty E_n\right)\leq\inf_{n\geq i}\mu(E_n)$
and by [this definition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Limit_superior_and_limit_inferior#Definition_for_sequences) you get
$$
  \lim_i\mu\left(\bigcap_{n=i}^\infty E_n\right)\leq\lim_i\inf_{n\geq i}\mu(E_n) = \liminf_n\mu(E_n)
$$

Answer (score 4):

For every $i\geq 1$ we have that 
$$
\bigcap_{n=i}^\infty E_n\subseteq E_i
$$
and so for all $i\geq 1$
$$
\mu\left(\bigcap_{n=i}^\infty E_n\right)\leq \mu(E_i).
$$
Then
$$
\mu(\liminf_n E_n)=\lim_{i\to\infty}\mu\left(\bigcap_{n=i}^\infty E_n\right)\leq \liminf \mu(E_i),
$$
using the fact that if $(x_n)_{n\geq 1}$ and $(y_n)_{n\geq 1}$ are sequences with $x_n\leq y_n$ for all $n$, then $\liminf x_n\leq \liminf y_n$.