# Prove $\limsup\mu(E_n)\leq\mu(\limsup(E_n))$ when $\mu(\bigcup E_n)<\infty$.

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

QUESTION

Let $(X,\alpha,\mu)$ be a measure space.
Let $(E_n)$ be a sequence in $X$.

Prove $\limsup\mu(E_n)\leq\mu(\limsup E_n)$ when $\mu(\bigcup E_n)<\infty$.

Show that this inequality may fail if $\mu(\bigcup E_n)=\infty$.

IDEAS

I was thinking of showing the reverse - $\mu(\limsup E_n)\geq\limsup\mu(E_n)$ because I know $\limsup E_n=\bigcap _{n=1}^\infty\bigcup_{m=n}^\infty E_n$. I know the measure of a union is equal to the union of the measures if the sequence is disjoint (which I am not guaranteed to have here). Besides I would have to deal with the intersection first.

I also have to prove a similar inequality for $\liminf$, but I figure I should be able to figure out the other if I can figure out one.

Please let me know what ideas you have.  Thank you!

Comment: possible duplicate of [An inequality about sequences in a $\sigma$-algebra](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/280840/an-inequality-about-sequences-in-a-sigma-algebra)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $A = \cup E_n$. By Fatou's lemma,

$$\int_A \liminf 1_{A\setminus E_n} \, d\mu \le \liminf \int_X 1_{A\setminus E_n}\, d\mu.$$

Thus

$$\int_A \liminf (1 - 1_{E_n})\, d\mu  \le \liminf \int_A(1 - 1_{E_n})\, d\mu$$

or

$$\mu(A) - \int_A \limsup 1_{E_n}\, d\mu \le \mu(A) - \limsup \int_A 1_{E_n}\, d\mu.$$

Since $\limsup 1_{E_n} = 1_{\limsup E_n}$, $\int_A 1_{E_n}\, d\mu = \mu(E_n)$, and $\int_A 1_{\limsup E_n}\, d\mu = \mu(\limsup E_n)$, we have

$$\mu(A) - \mu(\limsup E_n) \le \mu(A) - \limsup \mu(E_n).$$

Since $\mu(A) < \infty$, we deduce

$$\limsup \mu(E_n) \le \mu(\limsup E_n).$$

Comment: How I am allowed to just let $X=\bigcup E_n$?  Also, I am unfamiliar with the "1" notation - is it some sort of characteristic equation?

Comment: @fullyhip Saying $X = \bigcup E_{n}$ is just giving the union a name (the name $X$) so that we don't have to keep writing $\bigcup E_{n}$ over and over.  Also, since $E_{n}$ is a set for each $n$, of course you can take the union of all of these sets.  So it makes sense to talk about the union over all $n$ of $E_{n}$.

Comment: If $A$ is a set, then $1_A(x)$ equals $1$ if $x \in A$ and $0$ if $x \notin A$.

Comment: @kobe What is $1 - 1_{E_{n}}$?  Is that the constant function $1$ minus $1_{E_{n}}$?

Comment: @user46944 its $1$ minus the indicator function at $E_n$. So $(1 - 1_{E_n})(x)$ is $0$ if $x \in E_n$ and $1$ if $x \notin E_n$.

Comment: @kobe Oh yeah.  You are just rewriting $1_{X - E_{n}}$ as the difference of $1$ and $1_{E_{n}}$.  Thanks.

Comment: OK...I was confused because $X$ is the entire set...I can just rename.  : )  Now that I know we are talking about an indicator function, let me be re-evaluate...thanks!

Comment: I didn't realize $X$ was the entire set.  @kobe You should probably clarify why you are assuming the union of the $E_{n}$'s equals the entire set.

Comment: @user46944 I actually didn't notice that $X$ was already used to denote the entire space. I'll change the letter to $A$.

Comment: Excellent...GRAZIE MILLE KOBE!

Comment: Why $\int_A\liminf (1-1_{e_n})d\mu=\mu(A)-\limsup 1_{E_n}d\mu$?

Comment: @AndréGomes  $\liminf (1 - 1_{E_n}) = 1 - \limsup 1_{E_n}$.