# Measure theory sequence limsup

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure, borel-measures

Let $(X,M,m)$ be measurable space with measure $m$ and $(E_n)_n$ sequence in $M$. If $m\left( \bigcup_{k=1}^{+\infty}E_k \right)<+\infty$ prove that $$m\left(\bigcap_{n=1}^{+\infty} \bigcup_{k=n}^{+\infty}E_k\right)\leq{\limsup}_{n \to \infty}m(E_n)$$

I proved that $ \bigcup_{k=n}^{+\infty}E_k\supseteq \bigcup_{k=n}^{+\infty}E_{k+1}$ i.e sequence
$(\bigcup_{k=n}^{+\infty}E_k)$ is decreasing.After that i've used continuity of the measure to show that  $$m\left(\bigcap_{n=1}^{+\infty} \bigcup_{k=n}^{+\infty}E_k\right)={\lim}_{n\to\infty}m\left(\bigcup_{k=n}^{+\infty}E_k\right)$$
I don't know what next?
Any hint would be helpful.

Comment: Wait this is obviously false. I think you want the reverse inequality.

Comment: Maybe it's mistake in my paper.

Comment: I do want to refer to you the "Borel-Cantelli Lemma" to give $m(\limsup E_k)$ some meaning

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your inequality is backwards. Just note that $E_n \subseteq \bigcup_{k=n}^{+\infty}E_k$ so

$$ {\lim}_{n\to\infty}m\left(\bigcup_{k=n}^{+\infty}E_k\right) = \limsup_{n\to\infty} m\left(\bigcup_{k=n}^{+\infty}E_k\right) \ge \limsup_{n\to\infty} m(E_n)$$

Also have a look [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1169743/144766).

Comment: What's the difference between the two sides around the first = sign?

Comment: @GNUSupporter Nothing, just a typo.